# How to add aggregation dimensions to netcdf4 file with the Python library Xarray?

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am creating a netcdf file based on data from a pandas Dataframe with xarray. The data are one dimensional with only time as dimension.
 Then, the software I use this file for uses MFdataset() from the libray netcdf4 to open and load the data. Everytime I create a netcdf file (e.g. called `test3.nc`) using whichever engine or format available with the function `to_netcdf()`,  I then obtain the error `OSError: master dataset test3.nc does not have a aggregation dimension` when opening it with `MFDataset('test3.nc')`

```py
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
from netcdf4 import MFDataset

# create a dataframe
df = pd.Dataframe()
# [logic to add data with one column as time]

# convert dataframe to Dataset
fo = xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df.set_index('time'))

# add variable attributes here

# convert xarray Dataset to a netcdf file:
fo.to_netcdf('test3.nc', mode='w',format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')

MFDataset('test3.nc')
```

Then the following error comes in the console depite the fact that time is a dimension:

```py
MFDataset('test3.nc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arcticsnow/anaconda3/envs/dataAna/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-26-94430718f30a>", line 1, in <module>
    MFDataset('test3.nc')
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 5917, in netCDF4._netCDF4.MFDataset.__init__
OSError: master dataset test3.nc does not have a aggregation dimension
```

Comment: Found the solution myself. see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the following argument in the `to_netcdf()` function:

```py
fo.to_netcdf('test.nc',  unlimited_dims={'time':True}, format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')
```